# Table of Contents with Chapter

Tags: table-of-contents, chapters

I'm attempting to modify the Table of Contents in my document. Currently, chapter one in my document is listed as

```
1   Introduction
```

What I would like to see is

```
Chapter 1   Introduction
```

Seems like an easy enough thing to ask for, but can't seem to find a good way to do this. Any feedback would be most appreciative.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The [`titletoc` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/titletoc) provides ToC entry manipulation for a `\chapter` via `\titlecontents*{chapter}`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}% http://ctan.org/pkg/lipsum
\usepackage{titletoc}% http://ctan.org/pkg/titletoc
\titlecontents*{chapter}% <section-type>
  [0pt]% <left>
  {}% <above-code>
  {\bfseries\chaptername\ \thecontentslabel\quad}% <numbered-entry-format>
  {}% <numberless-entry-format>
  {\bfseries\hfill\contentspage}% <filler-page-format>

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{Introduction} \lipsum[1]
\section{First section} \lipsum[2-3]
\section{Second section} \lipsum[4-5]
\section{Last section} \lipsum[6-7]
\chapter{Second chapter} \lipsum[1]
\section{First section} \lipsum[2-3]
\section{Second section} \lipsum[4-5]
\section{Last section} \lipsum[6-7]
\chapter{Last chapter} \lipsum[1]
\section{First section} \lipsum[2-3]
\section{Second section} \lipsum[4-5]
\section{Last section} \lipsum[6-7]
\end{document}
```

For adding space between ToC chapter entries, you could use `\addvspace{1em}` (where `1em` is the regular `book` documentclass chapter skip) for `<above-code>`:

```
\usepackage{titletoc}% http://ctan.org/pkg/titletoc
\titlecontents*{chapter}% <section-type>
  [0pt]% <left>
  {\addvspace{1em}}% <above-code>
  {\bfseries\chaptername\ \thecontentslabel\quad}% <numbered-entry-format>
  {}% <numberless-entry-format>
  {\bfseries\hfill\contentspage}% <filler-page-format>
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Werner, pictures helped a lot in conveying the information. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: Dear Werner, I have two questions related to this post which I am having similar problems. a) I would like to ask how if I want to have the word "Chapter" in the capital letter "CHAPTER"?   b) If I use [\titlecontents*{chapter}% 
  [0pt]% 
  {\addvspace{1em}}% 
  {\bfseries\chaptername\ \thecontentslabel\quad}% 
  {}%
  {\bfseries\hfill\contentspage}% ] I get error message saying "chemmacros.sty" . undefined control sequence. Could you help to resolve this issue? Thank you.

Comment: @Vijay: (a) Use `\MakeUppercase{\chaptername}` or `CHAPTER` directly instead of `\chaptername`. (b) I don't understand what might be causing that.

Comment: @Werner, I am using "Easy thesis" template which is based on "book" type document class (https://www.sharelatex.com/templates/52fdfd8234a287a85245b4c6). After the "\begin{document}" command, there is another command "\frontmatter". So I am not so sure where I supposed to add the "command" you suggested in the post. Additionally, In the template the chapters are numbered like 1. Introduction, 2. Literature review, and so on. So I tried to make the word "CHAPTER" in front of the   chapter number but I fail. Hope you could help.

Comment: What if I have Acknowledgement, List of Figures et al. that precede the actual chapters and I only want actual chapters to have the word "Chapter before the numbering? In other words, how can I avoid having "Chapter List of Figures?"

Comment: This solution causes formatting problems in case some of the chapters have have no sections. egreg's answer works better for my case.

Comment: @TTT: In that case, you can add the optional `<below code>` provided by `\titlecontents`. See [this code](https://pastebin.com/raw/ar2ENnEP) that produces [this output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BGIA8.png).

Answer (score 15):

With `tocloft` one can use `\cftchappresnum` to put something before the number; but we have also to reserve enough space. I defer the space setting when the text font is already established.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{book}
\usepackage{tocloft,calc}

\renewcommand{\cftchappresnum}{Chapter }
\AtBeginDocument{\addtolength\cftchapnumwidth{\widthof{\bfseries Chapter }}}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\chapter{Introduction}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This also adds Chapter before Appendix. I wonder how to avoid this one. Thanks

Comment: This problem can be solved [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/56839/chaptername-is-used-even-for-appendix-chapters-in-toc).