# How can I add a word to all chapter titles in my document without also affecting the ToC?

Tags: table-of-contents, chapters

I'm writing a constitution-type document for a sports competition. I want each chapter heading to be preceded by the word "Article", viz: "Article 1  Rules of the competition", "Article 2  blah blah blah". So I added the following at the start of the document:

```
\renewcommand{\chapter}{\@startsection{chapter}{1}{0mm}{\baselineskip}{0.5\baselineskip}{\textsc{Article} \centering\sc\large}}
```

Unfortunately, this has also added the word "Article" to the title of the table of contents itself , so that it is now titled "Article Contents" instead of just "Contents".

How can I stop the word Article appearing in the title of the ToC? Or, is there a better way for me to add the word "article" to the header title for each chapter, but not the title of the ToC?

Comment: Maybe [this one](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/39153/18674) could give some hint to solve your question.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

One way is to get `\tableofcontents` to add the word for you after it has used the original definition

```
\makeatletter
\let\oldtableofcontents\tableofcontents
\def\tableofcontents{\oldtableofcontents\gdef\addarticle{\textsc{Article} }}
\gdef\addarticle{}

\renewcommand{\chapter}{\@startsection{chapter}{1}{0mm}{\baselineskip}{0.5\baselineskip}{\addarticle\centering\sc\large}}

\makeatother
```

Comment: which works in the usual case when ToC is at the beginning ;)

Comment: @tohecz well yes, otherwise you just need to move the `\gdef\addarticle{}` into the start of the `\tableofcontents` definition so that it resets it and then sets it back, and initialise it to say Article rather than nothing.