# Chapter Headings in TOC

Tags: table-of-contents, chapters, titletoc

I'm looking to accomplish what was shown here:
[Table of Contents with Chapter](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39153/table-of-contents-with-chapter)

Where the toc was changed from

```
  1 Introduction
```

to

```
Chapter 1 Introduction
```

Except I also have an abstract, acknowledgements, list of tables, and list of figures in the toc.

When I implement the solution my List of Tables, List of Figures, Acknowledgements and Abstract get piled on top of each other. My TOC compiled and looked fine (though not the way I wanted) before I added the \titlecontents block of code suggested in the above question.

[image: Piled TOC]

```
% MWE
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{titletoc}% http://ctan.org/pkg/titletoc
\titlecontents*{chapter}% <section-type>
  [0pt]% <left>
  {\addvspace{1em}}% <above-code>
  {\bfseries\chaptername\ \thecontentslabel\quad}% <numbered-entry-format>
  {}% <numberless-entry-format>
  {\bfseries\hfill\contentspage}% <filler-page-format>

\begin{document}

\setcounter{page}{2}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{1}
\tableofcontents
  \cleardoublepage
  \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\listfigurename}
  \listoffigures
  \cleardoublepage
  \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\listtablename}
  \listoftables
\cleardoublepage
\cleardoublepage
  \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Abstract}
  \cleardoublepage


\begin{abstract}
\thispagestyle{plain}
\pagenumbering{roman}
\setcounter{page}{9}
MWE
\end{abstract}

  \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Acknowledgements}
\setcounter{page}{10}
\section*{Acknowledgements}
\thispagestyle{plain}
I would....

\end{document}
```

Comment: Put the code `\titlecontents*{chapter}...` not in the preamble, but just before you start with your chapters.

Comment: I get undefined control sequence errors when I do that.

Comment: I mean all the code starting with `\titlecontents*{chapter}` and ending with `{\bfseries\hfill\contentspage}`

Comment: Yes I had an error in my preamble. Your fix solved it. Now the chapter numbers and section numbers are out of alignment. They are not in the examples from the question I link to.

Comment: It works fine for me