# Prepending "Chapter" except for appendix entry, and other requirements

Tags: table-of-contents

A more apt title to this is question may be "Jumping through hoops". My question is similar to [this one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39153/table-of-contents-with-chapter).

I have the following requirements for the table of contents in my thesis:

1. The title "Table of Contents" must be centered
2. Every chapter, section, subsection, and appendix must have dots between the chapter/section/etc name and the page number
3. The chapters must start out "Chapter #" for each entry in the ToC.

Following the second answer in the link above, I can get all three of these requirements using Tocloft, however it also puts "Chapter Appendix" which is not correct (see MWE below). Following the first answer, I no longer have this problem, but I can't get #2: there are no dots between the chapter name and the page number. Looking at the documentation for titletoc, it doesn't seem possible to include them (but maybe I'm missing something).

I would like to satisfy all three requirements but not have "Chapter Appendix". I am willing to use any package(s) to meet these.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{titlesec,tocloft,calc}

\renewcommand{\cftchappresnum}{Chapter }
\AtBeginDocument{\addtolength\cftchapnumwidth{\widthof{\bfseries Chapter }}}
\renewcommand\cftchapdotsep{\cftdotsep}
\renewcommand{\contentsname}{\vspace*{-1.75in}\hfill\bfseries\Large Table of Contents\hfill}   
\renewcommand{\cftaftertoctitle}{\hfill}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\chapter{Asdf}
\section{Foo}
\chapter{Jkl;}
\section{Bar}

\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\setcounter{tocdepth}{0}}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]{\centering\Huge\bfseries}{\thechapter}{0pt}{}
\appendix
\renewcommand{\thechapter}{}
\begin{chapter}{APPENDIX}
\renewcommand{\thechapter}{A}
\end{chapter}
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}}
\end{document}
```

Comment: @cslstr: Yes, thank you. I've commented the solution I linked to with the link you provided. This question should be marked as a duplicate and closed.