# Conditionally prepend text to chapter title in TOC

Tags: table-of-contents, conditionals, appendices, tocloft

I want to prepend some text to chapter titles on the TOC according to certain conditions. For example (this doesn't work):

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,openany,oneside]{book}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tocloft}

% If the chapter is an appendix, print "Apéndice", else "Capítulo".
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\cftchappresnum{
\ifx\@chapapp\appendixname
Apéndice\
\else 
Capítulo\
\fi
 }
\makeatother

\renewcommand\cftchapaftersnumb{\newline}
\renewcommand\cftchapleader{\cftdotfill{4}}
\renewcommand\cftchappagefont{\normalfont}
\setlength{\cftchapnumwidth}{0em}

\begin{document}    
\tableofcontents
\mainmatter
\chapter{First chapter}
  \section{First section}
  \chapter{Another chapter}
  \section{this is yet another section} 
\appendix
\chapter{First Appendix}
\end{document}
```

I know [this is a duplicate](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/168767/prepending-chapter-except-for-appendix-entry-and-other-requirements?lq=1), but I want to know if something like this is possible because I have to test for a number of conditions. Namely:

- Is this the first chapter of the TOC?
- Is this title equal to "foo"
- Etc.

Comment: If you used `memoir` instead, then the example would be defunct. There it is just `\renewcommand\cftchaptername{\chaptername~}\renewcommand\cftappendixname{\appendixname~}`. Don't know why this has not been added to `tocloft`.

Comment: The ToC is set at a different time than the actual document content. So a conditional based on `\@chapapp` would only work if it changed during the setting of the ToC, which it doesn't. Of course, one could do that, but there are other ways of doing this - by writing to the ToC to change the definition of `\@chapapp` at the appropriate moment.

Comment: Is there any news here?

Answer (score 1):

Since `\@chapapp` is explicitly used, just redefining it in `\cftchappresnum` is not sufficient if there is no information about the change in name at all, since the `ToC` is written at a time the information about `\@chapapp` change has gone to oblivion ;-)

It is better to write this information to the `ToC`, with `\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\renewcommand{...}}` (see the relevant line in the code.

Instead of fiddling with the explicit words for the `\appendixname` or `\chaptername` it is much better to let `babel` care about the change, unless one has very specific ideas about the names, deviating from the `babel` settings for this language.

Letting `babel` do the changes the code would work for any defined language.

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,openany,oneside]{book}


\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}

\usepackage{tocloft}

\usepackage{xpatch}


% If the chapter is an appendix, print "Apéndice", else "Capítulo".
\makeatletter
\DeclareRobustCommand{\gettherightprefix}{
  \renewcommand{\cftchappresnum}{%
    \@chapapp~%
  }
}
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \addtocontents{toc}{\gettherightprefix}% Just use the protected version of this instead of a lot of \protect statements
}
\xpretocmd\appendix{%
  % Inform the ToC that `\@chapapp` is `\appendixname now
  \addtocontents{toc}{\protect\renewcommand{\protect\@chapapp}{\protect\appendixname}}
}{\typeout{Success}}{\typeout{Failure}}

\makeatother

\renewcommand\cftchapaftersnumb{\newline}
\renewcommand\cftchapleader{\cftdotfill{4}}
\renewcommand\cftchappagefont{\normalfont}
\setlength{\cftchapnumwidth}{0em}

\begin{document} 
\tableofcontents
\mainmatter
\chapter{First chapter}
  \section{First section}
  \chapter{Another chapter}
  \section{this is yet another section} 
\appendix
\chapter{First Appendix}
\end{document}
```

[image]