# How do I format table of contents in my thesis?

Tags: table-of-contents, thesis

I am writing my thesis using my university's (Universiti Teknologi Malaysia) latex template. I have a problem with the table of contents. My working trial is as follows:

```
\documentclass[oneside,12pt,a4paper]{book}

\usepackage{tikz,UTMThesis,lipsum}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,matrix,positioning,shapes,arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric, arrows, calc, intersections}
\newcommand{\tikznode}[2]{\relax
    \ifmmode%
    \tikz[remember picture,baseline=(#1.base),inner sep=0pt] \node (#1) {$#2$};
    \else
    \tikz[remember picture,baseline=(#1.base),inner sep=0pt] \node (#1) {#2};%
    \fi}

\newcommand\summaryname{ABSTRACT}
\newenvironment{abstract}%
{\small\begin{center}%
        \bfseries{\summaryname} \end{center}}

\begin{document}    

    \tableofcontents
    \pagebreak

    \chapter*{DECLARATION}
    \chapter*{DEDICATION}
    \chapter*{ACKNOWLEDGEMENT}
    \chapter*{ABSTRACT}
    \chapter*{ABSTRAK}
    \chapter*{TABLE OF CONTENTS}
    \chapter*{LIST OF TABLES}
    \chapter*{LIST OF FIGURES}
    \chapter*{LIST OF ABBREVIATIONS}
    \chapter*{LIST OF SYMBOLS}

    \chapter{Introduction}
    \lipsum

    \section{lipsum}
    \lipsum

    \section{lipsum}
    \lipsum

    \section{lipsum}
    \lipsum

    \section{lipsum}
    \lipsum

    \chapter{ORDERING OF MATRICES BY PRECEDE OPERATOR}
     \cite{1198243,abdy2011transformation}

    \section{lipsum}
    \lipsum

    \section{lipsum}
    \lipsum

    \section{lipsum}
    \lipsum

    \section{lipsum}
    \lipsum

    \bibliographystyle{plain}     
    \bibliography{mydatabase}

    \chapter*{LIST OF PUBLICATIONS}

\end{document}
```

which produces a table of contents that looks like this:

[image]

I want my table of contents that looks like this one:

[image]

Please help.

Comment: For chapter title see [Werner answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/39159/108724). For `page number title` add `\addtocontents{toc}{~\hfill{Title}~\hfill\textbf{Page}\par}` after `\tableofcontents`.

Answer (score 1):

To get the sections in front of the main text included you either have to add them to the TOC manually `\addcontentsline{file}{sec_unit}{entry}`, here `file`=toc, or you divide your document in 3 parts using

```
\begin{document}    
\frontmatter
...
\mainmatter
[Your main work]
\backmatter
```

This will automatically include the chapters/sections in between \frontmatter and \mainmatter in the TOC without numbering them. In this case, you don't use the `*` when adding the respective `\chapter`s.

How to include the "CHAPTER" in front of the Chapter headings is described here:
https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/279319/189246