# Table of Contents with Chapter in PDF bookmarks

Tags: table-of-contents, formatting, pdf

I managed to add in the TOC the string `Chapter x` before each chapter title (following [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39153/table-of-contents-with-chapter)).

The chapter titles format was :

```
A Nice Title
```

They are now :

```
Chapter 1   A Nice Title
```

Everything works great.

But, in a second step, how do I proceed to add it **in the bookmarks displayed by the PDF viewers** ? Even more, how do I add it only for those include in the `\mainmatter` part ?

*Info : I use xelatex.*

[EDIT]

Here is a MWE :

```
\documentclass[a4paper,oneside]{book}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{titletoc}
\titlecontents*{chapter}
  [0pt]% <left>
  {}
  {\chaptername\ \thecontentslabel\quad}
  {}
  {\bfseries\hfill\contentspage}

\title{My document}

\begin{document}

\frontmatter
\chapter{Introduction} \lipsum[1]
\section{First section} \lipsum[2-3]
\section{Second section} \lipsum[4-5]
\section{Last section} \lipsum[6-7]

\mainmatter
\chapter{Second chapter} \lipsum[1]
\section{First section} \lipsum[2-3]
\section{Second section} \lipsum[4-5]
\section{Last section} \lipsum[6-7]
\chapter{Last chapter} \lipsum[1]
\section{First section} \lipsum[2-3]
\section{Second section} \lipsum[4-5]
\section{Last section} \lipsum[6-7]

\backmatter
\chapter{Conclusion}
\lipsum[8]

\tableofcontents
\end{document}
```

What gives :

[image]

I'd like the same format for the chapters titles in the PDF bookmarks. 
It seems that a solution could be found with the [bookmark package](https://ctan.org/pkg/bookmark)... but it's a mystery to me.

Comment: Can you make a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228)?

Comment: Hum... sure, I could. But is it really necessary in this case ?  There is no specificity here, it's a generic question. However, the one which is included in the linked post works.

Comment: As mentioned by samcarter, we will need a MWE as the solution will probably depend on the document class and preamble you use. BTW: the TOC by PDF viewers is often called the bookmarks.

Comment: @archi02 Even if there is nothing special in your MWE it will gve us something to start with and not having to start from scratch.

Comment: For example, I have a solution to this, but it relies on features in the memoir class that are not readily in other classes.

Comment: Ok guys, I got it. Sorry, I'm still not familiar with the uses. Here is a MWE. :-)

Comment: Very helpful are numbers in the bookmarks, see `hyperref` option `bookmarknumbered`. I would not add the prefix `Chapter`. Mostly the bookmarks are displayed in a narrow side bar. A long non-informative prefix just removes the informative title beyond the right margin.

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek I didn't know about this option either, and your advice makes sense. Perhaps, it will finally be the better solution...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably there is a much cleaner solution with bookmark, but you can patch hyperref internals:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}% http://ctan.org/pkg/lipsum
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{titletoc}% http://ctan.org/pkg/titletoc
\titlecontents*{chapter}% <section-type>
  [0pt]
  {}
  {\chaptername\ \thecontentslabel\quad}
  {}
  {\bfseries\hfill\contentspage}

\makeatletter
\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new:Npn\__hack_bookmarkprefix:w#1.#2\q_stop{
  \str_if_eq:nnT{#1}{chapter}{
    \chaptername\ #2\ 
  }
}
\cs_new:Nn\__hack_bookmarkprefix:n{
  \__hack_bookmarkprefix:w#1\q_stop
}
\cs_new:Nn\__hack_bookmark:nnnn{
  \@@BOOKMARK[#1][#2]{#3}{#4}
}
\cs_generate_variant:Nn\__hack_bookmark:nnnn{nnnf}
\RenewDocumentCommand\BOOKMARK{O{1} O{-} m m}{
  \__hack_bookmark:nnnf{#1}{#2}{#3}{\__hack_bookmarkprefix:n{#3}#4}%
}
\ExplSyntaxOff
\makeatletter

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\frontmatter
\chapter{Introduction} \lipsum[1]
\section{First section} \lipsum[2-3]
\section{Second section} \lipsum[4-5]
\section{Last section} \lipsum[6-7]

\mainmatter
\chapter{Second chapter} \lipsum[1]
\section{First section} \lipsum[2-3]
\section{Second section} \lipsum[4-5]
\section{Last section} \lipsum[6-7]
\chapter{Last chapter} \lipsum[1]
\section{First section} \lipsum[2-3]
\section{Second section} \lipsum[4-5]
\section{Last section} \lipsum[6-7]

\backmatter
\chapter{Conclusion}
\lipsum[8]
\end{document}
```

Comment: I've copy-pasted this code and launched it with xelatex. It stops with the error `! Undefined control sequence. l.27 \RenewExpandableDocumentCommand \BOOKMARK{O{1} O{-} m m}{` ... Did I do something wrong ?

Comment: Have you also copied `\usepackage{xparse}`?

Comment: You're version of `xparse` might also be too old. `\RenewExpandableDocumentCommand` exists since the `xparse` version from March 2017.

Comment: I edited the answer to be compatible with older versions.

Comment: Perfect! (indeed the version provided by ubuntu 17.04 is dated 2016-01-19, v6377). Thanks! :-)

Answer (score 2):

The following example uses package `bookmark` and its hook support to smuggle in the chapter prefix. Also the numbers are added by option `numbered` (package `bookmark`, that executes option `bookmarknumbered` of package `hyperref`).

```
\documentclass[a4paper,oneside]{book}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{titletoc}
\titlecontents*{chapter}
  [0pt]% <left>
  {}
  {\chaptername\ \thecontentslabel\quad}
  {}
  {\bfseries\hfill\contentspage}    

\usepackage{bookmark}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\AddChapterPrefixInBookmarks}{%
  \if@mainmatter
    \ifnum\bookmarkget{level}=0 %
      \preto\bookmark@text{\@chapapp\space}%
    \fi
  \fi
}
\makeatother

\bookmarksetup{
  numbered,
  addtohook=\AddChapterPrefixInBookmarks,
}

% Workaround for numbered sections in unnumbered
% chapter "Introduction" to avoid chapter number
% zero.
\renewcommand*{\thesection}{%
  \ifcase\value{chapter}%
  \else
    \thechapter.%
  \fi
  \arabic{section}%
}

\title{My document}

\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\tableofcontents
\chapter{Introduction} \lipsum[1]
\section{First section} \lipsum[2-3]
\section{Second section} \lipsum[4-5]
\section{Last section} \lipsum[6-7]
\subsection{Subsection}

\mainmatter
\chapter{Second chapter} \lipsum[1]
\section{First section} \lipsum[2-3]
\section{Second section} \lipsum[4-5]
\section{Last section} \lipsum[6-7]
\chapter{Last chapter} \lipsum[1]
\section{First section} \lipsum[2-3]
\section{Second section} \lipsum[4-5]
\section{Last section} \lipsum[6-7]
\subsection{Subsection}

\backmatter
\chapter{Conclusion}
\lipsum[8]

\tableofcontents
\end{document}
```

> [image: Bookmarks]

Comment: This works for me *if* I *comment out* the `\renewcommand*{\thesection}` part. Even unnumbered sections seems to work as they should (so the “workaround” doesn't seem necessary?). I’m using `XeTeX 3.14159265-2.6-0.999991 (TeX Live 2019/Debian)` on Ubuntu 20.04.

Comment: @zrajm I do not know, what you are doing. If the redefinition of `\thesection` is removed from the example in the answer, then the sections in chapter `Introduction` start with a chapter number zero: `0.1 First section`, `0.2 Second section`, ...

Comment: Well, I don't know what I'm doing either. :) – But it works just fine, and I'm not getting any extra zeroes. (So I'm happy.)

Comment: I'd like to be able to insert a dot, so that the chapter numbers in the table of content show up as `1. First Section`, `1.1. First Subsection` etc. (notice the dot after the number). I've been unable to insert one however – I'm assuming I need to know some low-lever TeX command that I don't know, maybe?

Comment: @zrajm It does not look like your problem is related to this question. Therefore, I suggest that you make a new question with a minimal, but complete example showing your problem.